# Deserialize nested object List in custom JsonConverter

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, json.net

I've made a custom JSON converter to handle the JSON that I receive, but I'm having some troubles parsing the nested object list. My JSON currently looks like this:

```
JSON:

{ 
"messageID": "1", 
"item": 
    { "type": "text", 
    "textlist": [ { "text": "just some text" }]
    }
}
```

In my case I created a few classes which can be converted to. I have a Message class which applies a converter to the item. The item property is an interface which has an implementation in the form of the TextItem class.

```
public class Message
    {
    [JsonProperty("messageID")]
    public string messageID { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(ItemConverter))]
    public IItem item { get; set; }

    public Message(string msgID, IItem itm)
    {
        messageID = msgID;
        item = itm;
    }
}

public class TextItem : IItem
{
    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public string type { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("textlist")]
    public List<Text> textlist { get; set; }

    string IItem.Type
    {
        get => type;
        set => type = value;
    }

    public TextItem(List<Text> txtlst)
    {
        type = "text";
        textlist = txtlst;
    }
}

public class Text
{
    [JsonProperty("text")]
    public string text { get; set; }

    public Text(string txt)
    {
        text = txt;
    }
}
```

There are quite a few different kind of items, which is why I have the ItemConverter:

```
public class ItemConverter : JsonConverter
    {
        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader,
        Type objectType, object existingValue,
        JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var jsonObject = JObject.Load(reader);
        var item= default(IItem);
        switch (jsonObject["type"].Value<string>())
        {
            case "text":
                item= new TextItem(jsonObject["textlist"].Value<List<Text>>());
                break;
    // omitted non relevant cases
        }

        serializer.Populate(jsonObject.CreateReader(), item);
        return item;
    }
}
```

However, calling the DeserializeObject only results in an error

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Message>(userMessage) 

// I get the following error:
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
```

All my other cases (without Lists) are handled just fine. Any ideas as to why the nested List is not properly converted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your classes are all messed up ,

use `public string type { get; set; }` to get your items that you need

your classes might look something like this

```
public class Textlist
{
    public string text { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public List<Textlist> textlist { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string messageID { get; set; }
    public Item item { get; set; }
}
```

and now you can deserialize on  `RootObject`

Comment: I fixed my classes as you described (also updated it in the original post). It still yields the same results though.